# (javascript) Pegar valor de um estrutura html bem complexa

Tags: javascript, html

Vou tentar ser bastante objetivo:

Como eu faço para pegar o valor dentro de uma tag que está dentro de 200 milhões de outros childs ?

(compreendendo desde já que eu não poderei fazer alterações no código, porque é o código de um site que preciso filtrar para colher dados específicos):

ex:

```
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <h1></h1>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
              <h1></h1>
                <div>
                  <div></div>
                  <div></div>
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr></tr>
                      <tr></tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <div></div>
                        <div>
                          <div>
                            <div></div>
                            <table>
                              <tbody>
                                <tr></tr>
                                <tr></tr> 
                              </tbody>
                            </table>   
                            <div></div>
...........
```

Por exemplo, eu preciso pegar as informações da segunda tabela (dentro das tags **TR**)... supondo que não existe id nem class, como eu faço para pegar essas informações ?

Grato.

Comment: Se você tiver base dessa estrutura pode usar `document.getElementsByTagName('table')` e daí pra selecionar use colchetes ([0],[1]), e pra achar o **TR** em questão repita o processo: `document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')`, se estiver certo disto user o innerHTML para pegar o conteúdo de dentro do dele:

`document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').innerHTML`

Comment: @RpgBoss Seu comentário está correto. Se possível adiciona como resposta. Você também pode adicionar exemplos com `querySelector` e `jQuery` para a resposta ficar bem completa.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando seletores do `jQuery` ou capturando todos os elementos e retornando apenas um deles através do índice.

#### document.getElementsByTagName

Com `document.getElementsByTagName('table')` você retorna um `array` com a *interface* [**HTMLCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Essa interface te dará a propriedade `length`. Essa propriedade irá retornar a quantidade total de elementos capturados com o código acima.

Além da propriedade mencionada, você também terá acesso a dois métodos;

- `HTMLCollection.item()`: Com esse método você poderá capturar o elemento através de seu índice *(que vai de `0..n-1`)*. É o mesmo que fazer `document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]` ou `document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1]`.

  *Caso o elemento não exista, retorna `null`*
- `HTMLCollection.namedItem()`: Retorna o nó especificado pelo ID ou, caso não tenha ID, o item cuja propriedade name seja igual à pesquisa.

  *Retorna null se nenhum nó corresponder ao nome pesquisado.*

```js
const segundaTabela = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1];
const dadosDaTabela = segundaTabela.getElementsByTagName("td");

// Percorre todos os valores
for (let i = 0; i < dadosDaTabela.length; i++) {
  console.log( dadosDaTabela[i] );
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Valor 1.1</td>
                  <td>Valor 1.2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Valor 2.1</td>
                  <td>Valor 2.2</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### document.querySelectorAll

Além da forma citada anteriormente, você também pode utilizar `document.querySelectorAll("table")`. Esse método não de trará um `array`, mas te retornará o objeto [**NodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (ou `Collection`) que funcionando semelhante ao `array`.

Essa interface também retornar a propriedade `length` com a quantidade total de elementos capturados.

Porém, ela trará uma quantidade maior de métodos. São eles:

- `NodeList.item()`: Com esse método você poderá capturar o elemento através de seu índice *(que vai de `0..n-1`)*. É o mesmo que fazer `document.querySelectorAll("table")[0]` ou `document.querySelectorAll("table")[1]`.

  *Caso o elemento não exista, retorna `undefined`*
- `NodeList.entries()`: Retorna um [iterador](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) que permite passar por todos os pares chave/valor contidos no objeto.
- `NodeList.forEach()`: Aqui você pode adicionar uma função de ``callback`. Assim ele percorrerá toda a lista enviando três argumentos para a função de`callback`. Os argumentos são: Elemento Atual; Índice Atual; Lista de objeto.
- `NodeList.keys()`: Semelhante ao `entries`, porém ele retornará apenas as chaves da coleção.
- `NodeList.values()`: Semelhante ao `entries`, porém ele retornará apenas os valores da coleção.

```js
const segundaTabela = document.querySelectorAll("table");
const dadosDaTabela = segundaTabela[1].querySelectorAll("td");

for (let resultado of dadosDaTabela) {
  console.log( resultado.innerText );
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Valor 1.1</td>
                  <td>Valor 1.2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Valor 2.1</td>
                  <td>Valor 2.2</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

Com `jQuery` fica tudo mais fácil, porém, muito código desnecessário nos "bastidores". Mas caso você já esteja utilizando em seu projeto (seja por gosto ou requisito de algum plugin), vale a pena utilizado. Caso contrário utilize [**VanillaJs**](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Com o `jQuery` você já pode informar o valor do índice através do seletor `:eq`. Ex:

```
$("table:eq(1) tr")
```

Pronto. Dessa forma você terá todos os `tr` da segunda tabela.

```js
$("table:eq(1) td").each( (index, el) => {
  console.log( el );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Valor 1.1</td>
                  <td>Valor 1.2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Valor 2.1</td>
                  <td>Valor 2.2</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você tiver base dessa estrutura pode usar `document.getElementsByTagName('table')` e daí pra selecionar use colchetes (ex.:[0],[1](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)), e pra achar o TR em questão repita o processo:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')
```

Se estiver certo disto user o **innerHTML** para pegar o conteúdo de dentro do dele:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').innerHTML
```

Agora outra maneira de trabalhar é usando `querySelector` segundo @Valdeir Psr
Por exemplo se você quiser selecionar automaticamente o primeiro **TABLE**:

document.querySelector('table')

Mas se quiser selecionar todos numa ARRAY:

```
document.querySelectorAll('table')
```

Depois o processo é igual ao primeiro exemplo.

Se preferir usar JQuery segue a mesma lógica para selecionar, só que escreve menos:

```
$("table")
```

Agora se você quiser selecionar entre arrays Ímpar ou Par pode usar assim:

```
$('tr:even') //Para Ímpar
$('tr:odd') //Para Par
```

As possibilidades são muitas mesmo, até envolvendo atributos, eu não achei nenhuma lista pronta melhor que essa de todos tipos de seletores:
[Jquery Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)